# Qt5 multi-threading: signals work in one-way only

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Here: [Qt multi-thread with GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547974/qt-multi-thread-with-gui/45550461) I've learned how to create a background worker (the `Engine` class).

In that class, I have a `QSerialPort` object, *that runs in the main thread* (see [How to setup QSerialPort on a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559610/how-to-setup-qserialport-on-a-separate-thread)).

I'm using the signal/slot mechanism to send/receive data. But it works in one-way only. The signals emitted from the `Engine` object ("worker thread") are received by the `QSerialPort` ("main thread"). The viceversa doesn't work: any signal emitted from `QSerialPort` is not received by the `Engine`.

engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

#include "myserial.h"

class Engine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Engine(QObject *parent = 0);

private:
    QTimer m_timer;
    MySerial m_serial;

signals:
    void serialSendMessage(QByteArray data);

private slots:
    void lineReceived(QByteArray line);
    void foo();

public slots:
    void run();
    void open(QString port, quint32 baudrate);
    void close();

};

#endif // ENGINE_H
```

engine.c

```
#include "engine.h"
#include <QDebug>

Engine::Engine(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Engine::foo);
    m_timer.setInterval(200);
}

// THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED!
void Engine::lineReceived(QByteArray line)
{
    qDebug() << line;
}

// THIS IS RECEIVED BY QSERIALPORT
void Engine::foo()
{
    emit serialSendMessage("Hello World!");
}

void Engine::run()
{
    // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
    connect(&m_serial, &MySerial::lineReceived, this, &Engine::lineReceived);

    // THIS WORK!
    connect(this, &Engine::serialSendMessage, &m_serial, &MySerial::sendMessage);
}

void Engine::open(QString port, quint32 baudrate)
{
    m_serial.open(port, baudrate);

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &m_timer, static_cast<void (QTimer::*)(void)>(&QTimer::start));
}

void Engine::close()
{
    m_serial.close();
}
```

MySerial.h

```
#ifndef MYSERIAL_H
#define MYSERIAL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>

class MySerial : public QSerialPort {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MySerial(QObject *parent = 0);
    bool open(QString port, quint32 baudrate);
    using QSerialPort::open;
    QByteArray sendMessage(QByteArray data, bool nmea);

signals:
    void lineReceived(QByteArray line);

private slots:
    void onReadyRead();
};

#endif // MYSERIAL_H
```

MySerial.c

```
#include "myserial.h"
#include <QDebug>

MySerial::MySerial(QObject *parent) : QSerialPort(parent) {
}

bool MySerial::open(QString port, quint32 baudrate)
{
    disconnect(this, 0, 0, 0);
    connect(this, &FemtoSerial::readyRead, this, &MySerial::onReadyRead);

    setPortName(port);
    if (!open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) return false;
    setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    setBaudRate(baudrate);
    setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    return true;
}

void MySerial::onReadyRead() {
    static QList<QByteArray> lines;
    static QByteArray buffer;

    buffer += readAll();
    int index = buffer.indexOf("\r");
    while (index != -1) {
        lines.append(buffer.left(index + 1));
        buffer = buffer.mid(index + 1);
        index = buffer.indexOf("\r");
    }

    // THIS SIGNAL IS EMITTED!
    while (!lines.isEmpty()) emit lineReceived(lines.takeFirst());
}

QByteArray MySerial::sendMessage(QByteArray data) {
    write(data);
    return data;
}
```

### EDIT

Trying to add a `QEventLoop`:

```
void Engine::run()
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(&m_serial, &MySerial::lineReceived, this, &Engine::lineReceived);
    connect(this, &Engine::serialSendMessage, &m_serial, &MySerial::sendMessage);    
    loop.exec();
}
```

The behavior is the same: the data is sent, but the receiving slot is never executed.

Comment: `void Engine::run()` connects a couple of signals and finishes with its thread immediately. It supposed to have the event loop as we told you for your last question.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't fully understand your comments. I'm re-reading them and the related links.

Comment: I give up, I cannot understand where and why I need `QEventLoop`. I move the whole `Engine` in another thread, I don't sub-class `QThread` (I tried to catch the `finished` signal and it doesn't fire). Furthermore the emitted signals work. Anyway, adding a `QEventLoop` in the `run()` function doesn't change the behavior. Would you mind to clarify me what's happening?

Comment: When void `Engine::run()` finishes its work the `Engine` thread is done. Call its base class. `QThread::run()` before exiting to have an event loop.

Comment: Uhm... but the `finished` signal is not emitted and it continues to send data! As said, adding a `QEventLoop` inside the run() function changes nothing. Would you please show me how should change the code?

Comment: Your sending is probably not happening in the thread. It's most likely running in the main thread.

Comment: MySerial exists in whatever thread that created the Engine. Not the engine thread.

Comment: @drescherjm I printed out the thread's address. The "sending" happens in the `Engine` thread (when emitting the signal) and ends in the main thread (when the slot is executed inside `QSerialPort`). And this unfortunately this does not help me.

Comment: @drescherjm correct! MySerial lives in the main thread, as said in the original question and as suggested in the link provided....

Comment: It's hard to debug this in my head.. You may need `Qt::QueuedConnection` on your connect()s however Qt should have complained to std::error about cross thread signal /slots.

Comment: @Mark, try not using additional thread. Use all signals and slots that help available and never block the thread until the condition is up. That will make things clearer.

Comment: @AlexanderVX of course if I don't use any thread all works fine! I've used this code for years. But now I want to use the threads. And I'm trying to understand how...

Comment: Then do not make child from QThread. It is never needed. Create some Worker derived from QObject and move it onto new thread. Connect signals/from to there.

Comment: The comment directly above this one is the official Qt recommended way. With that said I have successfully done threading in Qt both ways many times.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I'm sorry, I received a lot of suggestion but no working code... I tried to follow your hints but I can't understand what. I provided a minimal example as requested.

Comment: Is Qt complaining to stderror about your signal slot connections?

Comment: No, nothing appears on the output.

Comment: Did you try changing `connect(&m_serial, &MySerial::lineReceived, this, &Engine::lineReceived);` to `connect(&m_serial, &MySerial::lineReceived, this, &Engine::lineReceived,Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Comment: Yes, I've already tried - anyway the auto connection should automatically select the QueuedConnection due to the cross-thread connection.

Comment: Also any chance lineReceived() is emitted before the thread starts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151314/discussion-between-mark-and-drescherjm).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool MySerial::open(QString port, quint32 baudrate)
{
    //<s>disconnect(this, 0, 0, 0);</s> // <--- strikeout
    connect(this, &FemtoSerial::readyRead, this, &MySerial::onReadyRead);
    // ...
}
```

From the documentation:

> Disconnect everything connected to an object's signals
>
> disconnect(myObject, 0, 0, 0);

it means from the signals of `myObject` not the other way round.
That line prevents the slot in `Engine` to be executed because it has just disconnected from the source signal.

`Engine` might disconnect when the port closes, to avoid multiple connections on the next opening.